# How to get all ordered sublists from a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list: [1,2,3,4].  It could be much longer. There will be many more combinations. 
The values are less important. 1,2,3,4 is more about the sequence or index of the elements (I did not use 0 for the first element).

For now, I want to have:

```
   4-elements: [1,2,3,4]
   3-elements: [1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,3,4], [2,3,4]
```

or more generally, it will be nice I can specify the number of elements of the sublists.

I'm thinking using loops, pick up each element in order. To get four-elements, will take four loops. As the number of desired elements increases, it will become unmanageable. Just wondering if there is an easier solution.
Thank you!

Comment: can you show what you have been trying so far?

Comment: I'm thinking using loops, pick up each element in order. To get four-elements, will take four loops. As the number of desired elements increases, it will become unmanageable. Just wondering if there is an easier solution.

Comment: can you try and then say what is not good?

Comment: 4 or 3 nested loops are doable.  Pick the first one, then pick the second one from the rest of the list, pick the third one, then the fourth one, break if there are not enough elements left. It gets cumbersome when the number increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a `dict` with [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
{i: list(combinations(l, i)) for i in range(4, 2, -1)}
```

output:

```
{4: [(1, 2, 3, 4)], 3: [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]}
```

each key form the `dict` represents the number of elements from a combination

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much!